# Caught in a Casual Fling

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Spin me thrice and I end like this
> Thrice more and I end with meat
> Once more and I end with a stinger
> Thus spun all around,
> I'm played with by flingers

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are a:

> **FRISBEE**!

*Spin me thrice and I end like this*

> If we 'spin' (i.e. cycle through) the letters three times, moving them from the back to the front, we achieve BEEFR**IS**, which ends in 'IS' *like 'th**is**'*.

*Thrice more and I end with meat*

> Three more and we get RIS**BEEF**, which ends in 'BEEF' (a *meat*).

*Once more and I end with a stinger*

> One more: back to FRIS**BEE** (a BEE is a *stinger*).

*Thus spun all around,*
*I'm played with by flingers*

> This last move completes the cycle - our word has now been 'spun all around', echoing how a real Frisbee is tossed about by people throwing it from one to another (also echoed by the title imagery).